# Webscraping Reddit Comments Error: tlsv1 alert protocol version?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language. I found this interesting function over here that can supposedly webscrape Reddit comments: https://github.com/ctaggart878/RedditScraperSingleLink/commit/69fdddc9527445e574a248d03f4c0b33f8f8d8f4

```
wd = getwd()
postlink = "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/wg870o/oc_this_is_the_usa_section_at_my_local/"
```

I tried to run this code and got the following error:

```
redditScrape(postlink, plotCloud = TRUE, saveText = FALSE, myDirectory = wd)

 Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong or does this website simply block webscraping?

Thank you!

Comment: That code is almost 10 years old, so it may contain a few problems. However, it seems that the error you are getting is due to the script using an old security protocol. Maybe try httr::GET rather than rcurl::getURL

Answer (score 1):

Package `RedditExtractR` does the work for you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RedditExtractoR)

reddit_link <- "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/wg870o/oc_this_is_the_usa_section_at_my_local/"

get_thread_content(reddit_link) %>%  
  .$comments %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 499 × 10
   url      author date  timestamp score upvotes downvotes golds comment comment_id
   <chr>    <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     
 1 https:/… xentr… 2022…    1.66e9 25149   25149         0     0 "Halfw… 1         
 2 https:/… DrMan… 2022…    1.66e9  5898    5898         0     0 "Yeah,… 1_1       
 3 https:/… divin… 2022…    1.66e9   490     490         0     0 "Same.… 1_1_1     
 4 https:/… samue… 2022…    1.66e9   247     247         0     0 "I don… 1_1_1_1   
 5 https:/… Frowz… 2022…    1.66e9    16      16         0     0 "Ugh \… 1_1_1_1_1 
 6 https:/… digit… 2022…    1.66e9   238     238         0     0 "For m… 1_1_1_2   
 7 https:/… chemi… 2022…    1.66e9  2939    2939         0     0 "It wa… 1_1_2     
 8 https:/… bowse… 2022…    1.66e9   943     943         0     0 "How i… 1_1_2_1   
 9 https:/… Mayor… 2022…    1.66e9   933     933         0     0 "The b… 1_1_2_1_1 
10 https:/… bowse… 2022…    1.66e9   134     134         0     0 "Ha! T… 1_1_2_1_1…
# … with 489 more rows
```